# What is Android PDK?

Tags: android

Android SDK is used to build the Java Apps. Android NDK is used to build the Native part of the Android Application. Then what is Android PDK? Is PDK refer the target tool chain? Please throw some light one this.

Comment: Please refrain from flagging this person again! He is obviously new to the forum, and needs us to explain the concept rather than downvote him to oblivion! @Madison - I would advise you to read the FAQ and be more specific in your questions next time on.

Comment: Thanks Shouvik. I will read the FAQ and refine my future Qs.

Comment: This question is perfectly valid. Stackoverflow is my starting point if I need any programming information. Even if the information is found on google very fast there is no reason it should not be integrated in the SO knowledgebase, be explained, rated etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Android PDK](http://pdk.android.com/online-pdk/guide/index.html) is the Platform development kit. This is needed by manufacturers that want to build android powered devices or people building custom roms.

It consists of the tools needed to build the Android OS itself.

Comment: Thanks. Then PDK just refer to the (prebuilt) tools, which come with Android source, and build process.

Comment: The Android PDK link isn't working anymore. Why? Where can I find the online guide for Android porting!?

Comment: Closest I can find it a statement about sharing private code lines related to a small number of flagship devices. Android PDK is what is given to the flagship device vendors. https://source.android.com/source/code-lines#about-private-code-lines

Answer (score 3):

From [wladimir-tm4pda.github.io](https://wladimir-tm4pda.github.io/porting/index.html): "Welcome to the Android Platform Dev Guide! This guide provides an under-the-hood introduction to the Android platform, and is *designed for platform developers and manufacturers building Android-powered devices*."

That part in italics answers your question.