# What is the difference between aosp and android pdk?

Tags: android, pdk

First of all, I know the pdk definition. "platform development kit".
My question is the following.

I googled about android pdk and read some of them.
But I'm still curious what pdk is.

When I heard that google provides some leading manifactors the new version of android as pdk.
In this part, I'm curious.
If pdk consists of all source code, it's just the lastest android source which google tags, right ?

Someone said when google provide the pdk, some of new android source are provided as binaries. Is it true?

If someone has experiences with co-working with google, please let me know what is the pdk different from aosp.

ps.
I also read this question. ([What is Android PDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510142/what-is-android-pdk))

```
The Android PDK is the Platform development kit. This is needed by manufacturers that want to build android powered devices or people building custom roms.

It consists of the tools needed to build the Android OS itself.
```

According to the above answer, there is a menion like "pdk consists of the tools needed to build android". but aosp also has the tools to build android, what is different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android PDK is essentially Android Open Source Project (AOSP), *plus* some closed-source which is not included in AOSP. It is provided under a Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA), so you shouldn't expect to find any details online.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I've just checked the comment. If only difference is the platform components source, are the tools (SDK Platform-Tools) same 
between PDK and AOSP ?

Comment: Yes, they have the same SDK. The PDK is really for device manufacturers to allow them to integrate with their hardware, so the differences are all _behind_ the application-visible APIs: hence SDK is the same.